# Package dependency issues in Apache Karaf 3.x with Spring 3.2.x Spring-dm 1.2.1

Tags: spring, karaf

I am trying to deploy a camel bundle in karaf 3.0.1 which uses spring dm. When bundle is deployed, it is not getting resolved due to spring package dependency. Following are more details, please help me to resolve this issue. Do I need to revert back to spring 2.x version?

```
Complaining Package Dependency
------------------------------
org.springframework.osgi.context;version="[2.0,3)"


Installed Spring features
--------------------------
karaf@root()> feature:list -i | grep spring
camel-spring             | 2.13.0           | x         | camel-2.13.0            |                                                   
spring-dm                | 1.2.1            | x         | spring-3.0.1            | Spring DM support                                 
spring                   | 3.2.4.RELEASE    | x         | spring-3.0.1            | Spring 3.2.x support                              
spring-jms               | 3.2.4.RELEASE    | x         | spring-3.0.1            | Spring 3.2.x JMS support                          
spring-tx                | 3.2.4.RELEASE    | x         | spring-3.0.1            | Spring 3.2.x Transaction (TX) support             
spring                   | 4.0.2.RELEASE_1  | x         | spring-3.0.1            | Spring 4.0.x support 


Spring-dm feature info
----------------------

karaf@root()> feature:info spring-dm
Feature spring-dm 1.2.1
Description:
  Spring DM support
Feature has no configuration
Feature has no configuration files
Feature depends on:
  spring [2.5.6,4)
Feature contains followed bundles:
  mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib/3.0_1 start-level=30
  mvn:org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi-io/1.2.1 start-level=30
  mvn:org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi-core/1.2.1 start-level=30
  mvn:org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi-extender/1.2.1 start-level=30
  mvn:org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi-annotation/1.2.1 start-level=30
  mvn:org.apache.karaf.deployer/org.apache.karaf.deployer.spring/3.0.1 start-level=30
  mvn:org.apache.karaf.bundle/org.apache.karaf.bundle.springstate/3.0.1 start-level=30
Feature has no conditionals.
```

Comment: It seems that spring-dm does not work with Spring 4 (4.0.2 in your case). Also you have 2 spring there. Remove the 4.0.2 one

Comment: Thanks Luciano for your quick response. I have removed 4.0.2 version. But still I am having the same issue. Is spring-dm not working with spring 3.x versions?

Comment: I agree in replacing 4.0.2, and i would recommend to use gemini blueprint instead of spring-dm, cause spring-dm moved to eclipse a few years ago.  https://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/eclipse-migration.html

Comment: Thanks Martin, are you suggesting to use blueprint instead of spring? I have never tried it. Then what about other usages I am having with spring? I am really confused with this at the moment. Is this much hard to configure and run OSGi runtime?